# Is there a list of all player moves in Apocalypse World?

Tags: apocalypse-world

I find myself reading multiple playbooks to see if there are any particular moves from other playbooks that fit my own character. This strikes me as crushingly inefficient.

Is there a list of all Apocalypse World player moves (not generic moves) sorted in some useful form somewhere on the internet?

Comment: I'm not aware of any one, but that would be super useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just put the index of moves from the book up online: [AW-movesindex.pdf](http://apocalypse-world.com/AW-movesindex.pdf)

It's not the full text of the moves, and it doesn't include any of the limited edition playbooks, but it's a list, at least.

I wouldn't object to having a comprehensive list with the full moves online. Maybe I'll steal a few hours from myself and put one together sometime.

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome! Welcome to the site! That is *exactly* what I was looking for. An aide memoir to see "well, does this match up with what I want to do?"

Comment: @Vincent welcome to RPG.SE. We welcome your contributions. Its a happy site to see game authors contributing here.

Comment: Seriously. What would you know?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing like that exists online. I'm not sure what Vincent would think of such a publication either, since moves are the heart of a playbook. Apocalypse World isn't really about charop anyway, so efficiency isn't an important value for the author or the community. Discovery and synthesis is much more important.

The current situation really isn't that bad though: there are only so many moves in the standard playbooks and it doesn't take long to internalise the knowledge of which character archetypes have which moves. If you're playing with some of the additional playbooks, that process just takes slightly longer.

Besides, you won't really know what move you want until you actually play enough to earn the improvements that let you choose moves from other playbooks. Because a game of Apocalypse World is highly unpredictable, plotting a character's advancement ahead of time *à la* D&D is very ill-advised.

Comment: Fair enough, mate. To narrow down, I'd like a quick reference so that I can narrow down my search in the middle of a session when the MC asks me to level up, rather than a Pre-planned charOp. But good answer.

Comment: Now we know what Vincent Baker would think of it!

Comment: @jprete Yes! :D